# python I can not do my error handling well

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to do some error handling in the variable
re_gourp
below is my python script

```
try:
    with c1.cursor() as cursor:
         # if we start to feed all the data automatically, need to add impact by APAC into the sql
         sql = "select property.p_group, count(*) from incident where ...;"
         cursor.execute(sql, (a,b,c))
         re_group = cursor.fetchall()
         cursor.execute(sql, (_i_start,_i_stop,_p_group))
         re_group = cursor.fetchall()
         if re_group:
            print 'none'
            print re_group
            return {'p_group': _p_group, 'count(*)': 0}
         else:
            print 'value'
            print re_group
            return re_group



dashboard_a =  query_inc_group(i_start,i_stop,'a')
dashboard_b =  query_inc_group(i_start,i_stop,'b')
```

I need to do some error handling for re_group
but looks like it does not go into the if section, even I print '123'
Where could I implement my error handling?
because it return no data from sql at sometime
I need to assign it as '0' value
I use python 2.6

update: I have changed my program as you suggest
it will return

```
value
()
none
[{u'p_group': u'b', u'count(*)': 3}]
()
<type 'tuple'>
```

in my program
`dashboard_a` is `()` tuple
and 
`dashboard_b` is `[{u'p_group': u'b', u'count(*)': 3}]`

Comment: I have found that i should print after return ,change my program print before return

Comment: however, it is not go into if section , below is my data  ()
<type 'tuple'>
321
()
[{u'p_group': u'APAC EC', u'count(*)': 3}]
<type 'list'>

Comment: always in the else section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an empty result set, `cursor.fetchall()` returns an empty list, not `None`. You should simply check its boolean value, not compare it to `None`. Change your if-else block to something like:

```
   if re_group:
        print '321'
        return re_group
   else:
        print '123'
        print re_group
        return {'p_group': _p_group, 'count(*)': 0}
```

Comment: looke like when there is no result from my sql query, it will returns ()
<type 'tuple'>

Comment: I have changed my program in your way, but it didn't work ,

Comment: @ChesterLai That's an empty tuple. Same effect. If it doesn't work, edit your question adding an update explaining what happened.

Comment: looks like I put the wrong section , let me think for a while, sorry for bothering you

Comment: i have vote your answer, do you mean that? sorry for I don't familiar with the system